# Is XSS attack possible when filtering <tag? < tag is allowed

Tags: asp.net, xss

Is it possible to send XSS attack, if server filters , but <{space}tag> allows and sends back? It seems like browsers don't take < tag> as HTML tag :(

Server changes input only . (dots) to , (commas) and filters

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute attacks are still possible(breaking out of html attrbutes and adding javascript event handlers).

Comment: Can you give me an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

There are many other ways an XSS attack can occur, as mentioned in another answer. A good resources are

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Cross_site_scripting

Specific example:

```
<b onmouseover=alert('Wufff!')>click me!</b>
```

Comment: Server filters <b . There must be space after < (< b...>) is ok.